# How does an environment remember that it exists?

Tags: r, generator, local, environment

Take

```
adder <- local({
x <- 0
function() {x <<- x+1; x}
})
```

or equivalently

```
adderGen <- function(){
x <- 0
function() {x <<- x+1; x}
}
adder<-adderGen()
```

Calling `adder()` will return `1` calling it again returns `2`, and so on. But how does `adder` keep count of this? I can't see any variables hitting the global environment, so what is actually being used to store these? Particularly in the second case, you'd expect `adder` to forget that it was made inside of a function call.

Comment: Was the generator tag correct for this? I'm unsure if the second case is really a generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see what is happening, let us define the function as follows:

```
adderGen <- function(){
  print("Initialize")
  x <- 0
  function() {x <<- x+1; x}
}
```

When we evaluate it, we obtain:

```
adder <- adderGen()
# [1] "Initialize"
```

The object that has been assigned to `adder` is the inside function of `adderGen` (which is the output of `adderGen`). Note that, `adder` does not print `"Initialize"` any more.

```
adderGen
# function(){
#   print("Initialize")
#   x <- 0
#   a <- function() {x <<- x+1; x}
# }
adder
# function() {x <<- x+1; x}
# <environment: 0x55cd4ebd3390>
```

We can see that it also creates a new calling environment, which inherits the variable `x` in the environment of `adderGen`.

```
ls(environment(adder))
# [1] "x"
get("x",environment(adder))
# [1] 0
```

The first time `adder` is executed, it uses the inherited value of `x`, i.e. 0, to redefine `x` as a global variable (in its calling environment). And this global variable is the one that it is used in the next executions. Since `x <-0` is not part of the function `adder`, when `adder` is executed, the variable `x` is not initialized to 0 and it increments by one the current value of `x`.

```
adder()
# [1] 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Every function retains the environment in which it was defined as part of the function.  If `f` is a function then `environment(f)` shows it.  Normally the execution environment within `adderGen` would be discarded when it exited but because `adderGen` passes a function out whose environment is the execution environment within `adderGen` that environment is retained as part of the function that is passed out. We can verify that by displaying the execution environment within `adderGen` and then verify that it is the same as the environment of `adder`.  The `trace` function will insert the print statement at the beginning of the body of `adderGen` and will show the  execution environment each time `adderGen` runs.  `environment(adder)` is the same environment.

```
trace(adderGen, quote(print(environment())))
## [1] "adderGen"

adder <- adderGen()
## Tracing adderGen() on entry 
## <environment: 0x0000000014e77780>

environment(adder)
## <environment: 0x0000000014e77780>
```